# jQuery nested sortable with editable list items

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using the jQuery nested sortable [plugin](https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable), but I'd like to be able to edit the text of each list item, via a editablecontent='true' attribute.

[Demo of the code on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps90k57v/embedded/result/)

When I try this, however, I'm unable to modify the text of any list item.  I think it's because the entire list item is being used as a draggable piece (instead of just the bullet - which is what I'd like).  Is there any way to do this?

```
<script>
$('.sortable').nestedSortable({
        handle: 'div',
        items: 'li',
        listType: 'ul',
        isTree: true,
        toleranceElement: '> div'
    });});
</script>

<html>
<ul class="sortable">
<li><div>Some content</div></li>
<li>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <ul>
        <li><div contentEditable='true'>Some sub-item content</div></li>
        <li><div contentEditable='true'>Some sub-item content</div></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><div>Some content</div></li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the plugin you're using is suppressing the event.

One possible workaround would be to programatically trigger a `focus` event on the element when clicking it:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qkbhwcy5/)

```
$('[contentEditable="true"]').on('click', function () {
    this.focus();
});
```